# mapping c++ array to Eigen Matrix

Tags: c++, eigen

What I am currently trying to do is get the data from my variable input, convert it into and Eigen matrix, do some computation and then map the result back to an c++ array.

```
       void RBM::reconstruct(double *input, double *w) 
       {

              double *data = input;
              mexPrintf("\n");

           for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++){
             mexPrintf("%f", data[j]);
           }
                mexPrintf("\n");

            Map<MatrixXd> XX(data,6,6);
            MatrixXd resultEigen;
            double *result;

           Map<MatrixXd>( result, 6, 6 ) =   XX;
           resultEigen = XX.transpose();

           Map<MatrixXd>( result, resultEigen.rows(), resultEigen.cols() ) = resultEigen;
         }
```

The above code compiles but i get (run Time error) probably link to an access violation and i can't really figure out where the problem is. Thanks for any hint.

Comment: `result` is not allocated.

Comment: Hallo akakatak, i thought the allocation would be done Dynamically. i am not that familiar with Eigen Library.

Comment: Here is a [reference](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Map.html) about `Eigen::Map`. It says 'A matrix or vector **expression** mapping an **existing array** of data.'  **expression** means this object does not hold any data in rum-time. it's only a wrapper. **existing** means you have to prepare an array because this object is only a **expression**.

Comment: I don't think this has nothing to do with MATLAB!

Comment: If I am not wrong, you should be able to fix the issue by `double *result[6*6];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstand what a `Eigen::Map` is. The map wraps an existing memory block and allows you to use Eigens functionality on that block. With a `Eigen::Map` Eigen does handle any of the memory allocations. This allow you to manipulate the data in objects from other libraries without copying back and forth. As mentioned [in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34177938/mapping-c-array-to-eigen-matrix#comment56102650_34177938) [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34177938/mapping-c-array-to-eigen-matrix#comment56103549_34177938) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34177938/mapping-c-array-to-eigen-matrix#comment56104133_34177938), if you allocate the `result` array as `double result[36];` the program should run fine.

Comment: Just tried it with double result[36] and it actually runs. thanks again to Avi Ginsburg and all the others  for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <kdl/jntarray.hpp>

Eigen::MatrixXd mat_1, mat_2;
KDL::JntArray arr;

mat_1 = arr.data.matrix() - mat_2 ;
```

Here, array is converted to matrix